# How to make a re-entrant Boost coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

I'm using [Boost coroutine library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html), and I need my coroutine to be re-entrant.

This means I should be able to start the coroutine **from the beginning** multiple times.

What are some options?

My current workaround is to re-create the fresh coroutine every time:

```
boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::pull_type *source = new boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::pull_type(
            [&](boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::push_type& sink){
    sink(0);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
});
(*source)();

source = new boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::pull_type(
            [&](boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::push_type& sink){
    sink(0);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
});
(*source)();

source = new boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::pull_type(
            [&](boost::coroutines::coroutine<int>::push_type& sink){
    sink(0);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
});
(*source)();
```

Comment: What about the leaks?

Comment: @Manu343726 `delete` calls not shown for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the coroutines from boost.coroutine are stackfull you can't start them multiple times.
It is not clear from your example what you want to do:

- print "Hello world!" mutiple times -> use a loop inside the coro-fn
- some kind of backtracking/checkpointing -> could be done with coroutiens, but needs some additional work

Answer (score 0):

I don't at all see what's wrong with creating a fresh coroutine every time - they're not expensive to create.

If you have a lot of data in your coroutine so it's expensive to construct, move it all off into some data class and pass a reference to it to your coroutine.